# Как правильно подключить kartik range slider в ProductPitSearch?

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет.

Объясните как мне правильно подключить kartik range slider в ProductPitSearch или мне надо отдельно форму для него???
Если отдельно, то тогда как потом правильно искать и выводить???

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он подключается во view к форме, к любому полю вашей модели или serach-модели.

```
echo $form->field($model, 'rating')->widget(Slider::classname(), [
    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'min'=>0,
        'max'=>20,
        'step'=>1
    ]
]);
```

Этот пример самый первый в [документации](http://demos.krajee.com/slider#usage).